# fputcsv and integer typcasting to string

Tags: php, excel, csv, fputcsv

So I have a line that I want to do a fputcsv on that has some integers (that I need to be treated as strings but they are numbers). These integers have leading zeroes that get cut off when I do the fputcsv but I don't want that to occur, is there any way around this? I tried just typcasting as (string) and putting my variable in quotations but the only way I have found so far is to just put quotes around the entire number which leads the quotation marks to be shown in the csv file when I open it up in excel, which I don't want to occur. Does anyone know of a way to get this to work? I think the fputcsv is just automatically assigning this variable a type for some reason and making it a integer or something...

EDIT Example Text:

What I fputcsv:

```
02305109
```

What I get in the csv file opened in excel:

```
2305109
```

but the leading zero is still there when I just use vi to open said csv file. Really strange.

Comment: Additionally, when I put quotes around the string before the fputcsv the file has triple quoted it rather than just putting one set of quotes.. really odd.

Comment: How do you know it is not excel stripping the leading 0?

Comment: If you use the Excel text import wizard to open the CSV you can tell Excel to treat that column as text.  Padding numbers with leading "0" is a pain in Excel (and elsewhere) and best avoided if possible.

Comment: [See it here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5703962/1422309).

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem for long numbers which I wanted as a string.
Wrap it in single quotes and make it evaluable.

'="' . $yourNumber . '"'

Answer (score 7):

Try prepending (or appending) your leading-zero integers with a null character.

```
$csv[0] = 02392398."\0";
```

Answer (score 3):

Excel is interpreting the value as a number and formatting it as so. This has nothing to do with php.

This SU post has some information: https://superuser.com/questions/234997/how-can-i-stop-excel-from-eating-my-delicious-csv-files-and-excreting-useless-da

Comment: I have had this issue before. Excel tried to be smart but is quite stupid when it comes to casting and default preferences. Seems such a simple thing that could have been fixed a decade ago

Comment: False. Formating a proper csv means enclosing strings with quotation marks. If you use fputcsv there is no option to encase the numbers as a string that I can find anywhere.

Comment: you can edit the ouput of the csv cell value as a formula, so you would do something like :    $lines["mobile_phone"]="=\"".$lines["mobile_phone"]."\"";

Answer (score 2):

output it as a formula, so as:

$line["phone"]= "=\"" .$line["phone"]. "\"";

Answer (score 2):

It is too simple my code is

```
//header utf-8
fprintf($fh, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
fputcsv($fh, $this->_head);
$headerDisplayed = true;
//put data in file
foreach ( $this->_sqlResultArray as $data ) {
    // Put the data into the stream
    fputcsv($fh, array_map(function($v){
        //adding "\r" at the end of each field to force it as text
        return $v."\r";
    },$data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a quote to the beginning of the number:

```
'123456
```

and excel will not format this cell as a number.

Comment: This does not work (in Excel 2010 anyway).  CSV files with a quote like above will show a literal quote in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a single quote to the beginning of the data will solve the problem.

i.e '930838493828584738
instead of 930838493828584738 which converts to this 934E+n

If the csv file is provided by a third party, this could be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

format the column using `"00000000"`

This has the advantage that it will preserve the format on save

Comment: This doesn't work (in Excel 2010 anyway).  The leading zeros appear to be lost and can't appear again no matter what formatting you use afterward.

Comment: @psynnott, it works in every version of Excel I have used, from v2.x to 2013.  make sure you are going to Custom format, and typing in  the amount of zero's you want to appear. on a reload of the file, they will disappear again, but that's an annoyance of excel. If you look at the file in a text editor, you will see all the relevant zeros

Comment: Yea, unfortunately my users are going to open a CSV in Excel by default 99% of the time and complain about formatting not being what they expected.  Of course, asking them to do a bit of (understandable) work to fix it is received with sighs and complaints :)  I hate programming sometimes!

Answer (score -2):

Try a leading apostrophe (single quote). IIRC that keeps the leading zeros but doesn't appear in Excel.

Comment: @grubber which requires the Excel user to know what they are doing.  In 99% of the cases this won't be the case!